# Eliminate airspace issues in wpf with PrintWindow and interopbitmap

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, winapi

I have a question about a possible fix for airspace issue in wpf. By airspace i mean the problem of using wpf and win32 windows at the same time and the fact that win32 windows come on top always.

I have a win32 window that I want to incorporate into my wpf app. But I want to use all the fancy wpf stuff there also (like putting something above it etc..).

I know this is not possible because of airspace issues.

My win32 window is only a video window so it has no keyboard or mouse active parts. So my idea was to copy window content periodically using PrintWindow win32 function into some memory space where I would pick it up using Interopbitmap then I could use that interopbitmap as a source.

Also I would hide that win32 window so its not showing (supposedly printwindow works off hidden windows).

Unfortunately I don't know much about win32 programming so I failed so far. Does anyone else have experience with this? Or maybe has another solution for escaping the airspace issues?

I was doing something like this

```
this.dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
Utilities.GetClientRect(this.hwnd, out rect);

width = rect.Right;
height = rect.Bottom;

this.dc = Utilities.CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr.Zero);
this.hBitmap = Utilities.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, width, height);
Utilities.SelectObject(this.dc, this.hBitmap);
this.BitmapSource = (InteropBitmap)Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(this.hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```

and then periodically from another thread (5 times per second) i did this

```
Utilities.PrintWindow(this.hwnd, dc, WindowPart.Client);
this.dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, (Action)this.BitmapSource.Invalidate);
```

I just got a black screen so that obviously doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain 'airspace'.

Comment: PrintWindow() isn't guaranteed to work.  It must be implemented by the programmer that wrote the message handler for the window, responding to the WM_PRINTCLIENT message.  Usually easy to do, sometimes not, very often overlooked.  Black is the result.  Contact the original programmer for support.

Comment: Do you know of a better way to copy content of a screen to memory for later consumption? Something that works regardless of the programmer who made the program that is being screenshoted? I would use that memory for somehow connecting it to interopbitmap